# Update AWS ECS Task Definition with Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ecs, aws-powershell

long story short, I need to update my ECS Task definition via powershell in order to increase the "EphemeralStorage_SizeInGiB" which is only available via the AWS cli.

I am able to successfully grab the task via the Get-ECSTaskDefinitionDetail cmdlet but I'm stuck on what to do next.

I was able to convert that output to JSON and update the ephemeral storage field in the json file but cannot figure how to send that back to AWS. All my attempts with the Register-ECSTaskDefinition Cmdlet seem to fail as it wants individual arguments for each parameter instead of a json upload.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: It's not "only available via CLI, it is also available via API". Any reason you have to use the Powershell tools, instead of the standard AWS CLI tool? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html The standard tool supports passing in JSON.

Comment: Ended up going this route. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I don't have one to test with, but *most* AWS cmdlets return objects which can be piped to each other. [Get-ECSTaskDefinitionDetail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-ECSTaskDefinitionDetail.html) does too, returning an [DescribeTaskDefinitionResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ECS/TDescribeTaskDefinitionResponse.html) object, with what looks like all the right properties to auto-fill the registration. Try out

```
Get-ECSTaskDefinitionDetail -TaskDefinition $ARN | 
  Register-ECSTaskDefinition -EphemeralStorage_SizeInGiB $newSize
```

Or it might require using this `.TaskDefinition` property:

```
$Response = Get-ECSTaskDefinitionDetail -TaskDefinition $ARN
$Response.TaskDefinition | Register-ECSTaskDefinition -EphemeralStorage_SizeInGiB $newSize
```

and maybe it's that easy?

note that you must not use `-Select` in the Get command, or it will return a different object type.

---

That said, it's pretty awkward that it won't take json when two of its parameters do. Might be worth reopening this feature request:

https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/184